# Xamarin.Forms: In-App Updates not find new releases

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I would like to use In-App Updates to distribute public updates via AppCenter.
I followed this guide carefully:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin

and I configured the AppCenter Distribute module in the native application as follows:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate(bundle);

  Distribute.ReleaseAvailable = OnReleaseAvailable;    
  Distribute.NoReleaseAvailable = OnNoReleaseAvailable;
  Distribute.SetEnabledForDebuggableBuild(true);  

  AppCenter.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose;
  AppCenter.Start("android= [ ... ]", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
         
  LoadApplication(new App());
}

private bool OnReleaseAvailable(ReleaseDetails releaseDetails)
{
 string versionName = releaseDetails.ShortVersion;
 string versionCodeOrBuildNumber = releaseDetails.Version;
 string releaseNotes = releaseDetails.ReleaseNotes;
 Uri releaseNotesUrl = releaseDetails.ReleaseNotesUrl;

 // custom dialog
 var title = "Version " + versionName + " available!";
 Task answer;

 // On mandatory update, user can't postpone
 if (releaseDetails.MandatoryUpdate)
 {
     answer = App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, releaseNotes, "Download and Install");
 }
 else
 {
     answer = App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, releaseNotes, "Download and Install", "Maybe tomorrow...");
 }

 answer.ContinueWith((task) =>
 {
     // If mandatory or if answer was positive
     if (releaseDetails.MandatoryUpdate || (task as Task<bool>).Result)
     {
         // Notify SDK that user selected update
         Distribute.NotifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.Update);
     }
     else
     {
         // Notify SDK that user selected postpone (for 1 day)
         // This method call is ignored by the SDK if the update is mandatory
         Distribute.NotifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.Postpone);
     }
 });

 // Return true if you're using your own dialog, false otherwise
 return true;
}

private void OnNoReleaseAvailable()
{
AppCenterLog.Info("Log", "No release available callback invoked.");
}
```

However, the OnReleaseAvailable method is never triggered.
This is the AppCenter log when the AppCenter.Start() method is called:

[AppCenter] HTTP response status=404 payload={"code":"not_found","message":"Error: No public releases found for appId: 67168064-b072-430e-b513-25171d1e8b5d"}
[AppCenterDistribute] No release available to the current user.
[AppCenterDistribute] Calling listener.onNoReleaseAvailable.

The new release has been correctly submitted on Google Play store through AppCenter and the update is available. Therefore, why is the release never found?

Comment: [I don't think this applies, given the error message, but want to know if this gives the same error message, or what happens exactly.] As a test, if you add code to manually check for updates (perhaps on a button), what happens? `Distribute.CheckForUpdate();`

Comment: I tried, but nothing changes. OnNoReleaseAvailable callback is triggered.

Comment: Please make sure that you have new release for this app in the right group. It can't detect release if it not exist in the correct group.
Also we are not recommend use App Center Distribute module in apps for Google Play.
Please see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin#remove-in-app-updates-for-google-play-builds).

Comment: **I believe the situation is this:** The documentation does not explain well the difference between *AppCenter* release vs *Store* release. The AppCenter SDK calls are ONLY used when people download - and update - from AppCenter (not from Google Store). This can be public. But you would direct interested people to AppCenter, NOT to Play Store. Google has their own update mechanism. As @Anastasia's link explains, when you publish to Store, you first make a GooglePlay project configuration that puts dummy stubs in for `Distribute`. These do nothing - there will never be a release seen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then I think the documentation is a bit misleading.